# C# boolean compare vs set performance

Tags: c#, performance

In C#, suppose I have a `foreach` loop and it is possible that the iterator will be empty. Following the loop, more actions need to be taken only if the iterator was not empty. So I declare `bool res = false;` before the loop. Is it faster to just set `res = true;` in each loop iteration, or to test if it's been done yet, as in `if (!res) res = true;`. I suppose the question could more succinctly be stated as "is it faster to set a `bool`'s value or test its value?"

In addition, even if one is slightly faster than the other, is it feasible to have so many iterations in the loop that the impact on performance is not negligible?

Comment: You are more than likely overthinking this... But go ahead and test it yourself with the StopWatch class...

Comment: Side question - do you have some performance issues with any of these approaches?

Comment: This seems like an extreme overkill...

Comment: You'd be better off spending your time on things that matter.  Look at [this post](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) on Eric Lippert's blog.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy lol.

Comment: I doubt you will even be able to measure the difference.

Comment: @RexM Perhaps if he runs it within a loop like millions and millions of time...

Comment: what kind of loop are you taking about?

Comment: Does the item you are iterating over have count or length? if so then just test them and forget the bool all together. if(item.count > 0) or if(item.Length > 0) you get the idea.

Comment: @Areks thanks for pointing me to `StopWatch`, didn't know about that. All: I think it's obvious from my question that I know the impact would be small, the question is more academic than practical. Still, I don't think it's worthless to consider such things as a matter of curiosity.

Comment: @Areks then the question would be "why the hell are you looping millions and millions of times?" not "I wonder if we can make it faster by changing the read/assignment of a bit value"

Comment: @RexM What I tried to say is that you would need to iterate millions and millions of times to measure if there's any difference. Not in a real world situation. Just a quick test method.

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? Is it now a requirement on SO that any performance-related questions are prefaced with "**I AM NOT PLANNING TO OPTIMIZE PREMATURELY**"?

Comment: Thank you Ben, I was just about to add a similar comment. I'm so sick of hearing "thinking about this was a waste of time." I'm not asking what I should spend my time thinking about. The second paragraph of my question clearly shows that I realize how small the difference would be. The point is that I was writing the code, the two different ways occurred to me, and I was curious enough to take 10 minutes to ask the question. I couldn't care less about people's opinions on whether that's a waste of time.

Comment: You should probably be using `Task.WhenAny`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To kill a few minutes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool test = false;

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            if (!test)
                test = true;
        }

        sw.Stop();


        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + ". Hi, I'm just using test  somehow:" + test);
        sw.Reset();
        bool test2 = false;
        sw.Start();

        for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
                test2 = true;
        }

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + ". Hi, I'm just using test2 somehow:" + test2);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Output:
448
379

So, unless missed somthing, just setting the value is faster than checking and then setting it. Is that what you wanted to test?

EDIT:

Fixed an error pointed out in the comments. As a side note, I indeed ran this test a few times and even when the miliseconds changed, the second case was always slighty faster.

Comment: +1, this is exactly what I wanted to test. Thank you for introducing me to `StopWatch`. And thank you for simply answering the question rather than attacking me for asking it. Your results make it clear that just setting every time is indeed faster but as I suspected, the difference is negligible even at the 100 million iterations you did.

Comment: test2 gets compiled out because it's never used.

Comment: @Jonesy great observation, so this example would need to use `test2` after the stopwatch is stopped to accurately measure.

Comment: Thank you @Jonesy! I fixed it. Hope it's now correct!

Comment: Wonder if adding sw.Reset() below the second Console.WriteLine will have a different result on the time stamps, I think it will. Sense if(!test) test = True means that test is always True then the compiler should optimize these lines to be the same. test = True in both loops.

Answer (score 2):

`if (!res) res = true` is redundant.

The compiler should be smart enough to know that `res` will always end up being true and remove your `if` statement and/or completely remove the set altogether if you compile with Release / Optimize Code.

---

To your question itself. It should be faster to set a primitive value than to actually compare and set. I highly doubt you would be able to accurately measure the time difference at all on a primitive and just thinking about this alone consumed more time than the process will in `x` exagerrated iterations.

Comment: "It should be faster to set a primitive value than to actually compare and set" For loops iterated over many times it's more of a question of set vs. compare, rather than set vs. compare-and-set.

Comment: Also, `if (!res) res = true` is not redundant if it's possible that line of code is never reached. Which is why I said the iterator could be empty.

Comment: @andrew.cuthbert It is redundant -- you have no logic. It may be `false` before your if is called, but no matter what, it is always true afterwards. The compiler will not leave that statement the way it is.

Comment: @TyCobb Ah I see now, since the compiler knows it's faster to just set the value that compare it, it just gets rid of the compare. Is that correct?

Comment: @andrew.cuthbert I don't think it's so much as it being faster, but rather there is no need for the check.

Comment: @TyCobb I suppose logically there is no need for the check, but wouldn't it be true that if the check was faster than the set it would technically improve performance?

Comment: @andrew.cuthbert If your application is that performance-critical then you'd have rather more problems to worry about than that! However, in the world where processors can "look ahead" and "anticipate" forthcoming instructions, a branch (especially a condition branch) is an expensive operation compared to a simple value assignment.